# why useState object value is undefined in first time component render in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-effect

i have set one product details to setProduct use state in function fetchProduct().

```
const [ product, setProduct ] = useState({})

const fetchProduct = () => {
    const apiURL = //api url;
    fetch(apiURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        setProduct(res.data[0])
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

after i have call this function inside useEffect hook. and i have checked   product is set or no in call with colsole log

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct()
    console.log(product)

    return () => {

    }
},[])
```

following result i have get in console

```
{}
```

then i have refreshed again result is showing in console. why in first time result is empty object. thanks for help

Comment: It is an empty object initially because that's what is being chosen as the default value in `useState({})`.

Comment: hey thanks for reply, how can i implement api fetch function inside of useState() as initially

Answer (score 0):

fetch product is asynchronous as is setState your console log executes before the data is retrieved and set

Answer (score 0):

There are several behaviors for useEffect and it's dependency array:

In your example you use an empty array which  acts as- `componentDidMount` and runs once.

that's why when you refresh your component it doesn't hold the default value anymore which is {}, but the value that was changed by your function.

In this case i'd add `product state` to the dependecy array which will cause the useEffect to execute the code inside the useEffect once on mount and whenever the
`product state` changes

for more https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect when javascript start executing

> FetchProduct it continue to compile the next line it wont stop till the function execution finishes and then continue.
> If you want to access product and do whatever you want with it you can use another use Effect right after yours.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Here you can access the product
  console.log(product);
}, [product])
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have checked with another use effect as you mentioned above but i get result is, first is empty object and next product object showing when component render once. i have look a solution, product object will show first time. thanks for help